# How to cut object like this?

Tags: modeling

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to cut through the object like this?

Comment: Hello. It seems like some addon is used here. What's the gif source? That might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found the addon called box cutter. Seems like it can do the same thing.